# javascript replacement for prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery

i currently have code that prompts user for input and saves that input into a variable:

```
var userInput = prompt("enter input");
```

i am looking for something that can replace prompt (preferably using jquery since the rest of my code already uses that) but still allow me to grab the input as a variable.  I've tried using simple-alert, simple-modal, and a few others, and maybe i'm misunderstanding how, but i was unable to figure out how to grab the input outside of the function that is called on input

Comment: If you expect help with what you have tried, you should also show what you have tried.

Comment: jquery ui dialog modal form

Comment: are you using asp.net along with jquery/javascript?

Comment: html5 is what i am using with jquery/javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have tried using jQuery UI modals, you should probably include some of the code you have attempted in order to find the bug/confusion.

Per the [jQuery UI Documentation](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form), if you have a Modal Form with:

```
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
```

When the user clicks the button that confirms the prompt, which triggers a `function addUser()`, you will be able to access what is currently inside of the `<input>` element with:

```
var nameInput = $('#name').val();
```

If this is still confusing for your or doesn't work as intended, try to follow the example given by the [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form). View the example code by click 'View Source' near the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

here is my sample code that isn't working because while alerts work great, prompts do not because they are async:

```
<html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">
</head<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
foo
<script>
var input = '';
swal({
   title: "An input!",
   text: "Write something interesting:",
   type: "input",
   showCancelButton: true,
   animation: "slide-from-top",
   inputPlaceholder: "Write something" },
   function(inputValue){
     if (inputValue === false) return false;
     if (inputValue === "") {
     swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
     return false
   }
   input = inputValue;
});

alert(input);

</script>
</body></html>`
```

i have also tried the same thing but instead of declaring var input early on, doing var input = swal({...

Comment: i think i might be able to use a callback to streamline what i need to be synchronous -- i'm experimenting with it now